# cómo usar varios formularios en una página sin que dejen de funcionar

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, blogger

sucede que tengo un formulario de **blogger** este formulario necesito usarlos 5 veces en una misma entrada, tienen diferente diseño, pero pasa que solo funciona 1 de los 5, no sé si es porque a todos los marca como el mismo, o porque están en la misma entrada ¿qué puedo hacer para que me funcionen todos en la misma entrada? antes funcionaban pero ya no.

```
<div class="widget ContactForm" data-version="2" id="ContactForm1">
   <h3class="title">Formulario de contacto</h3>
   <div class="contact-form-widget">
      <div class="form">
         <form name="contact-form">
            <p></p>
            Nombre<br><input class="contact-form-name" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="name" size="30" type="text" value="">
            <p></p>
            Correo electrónico<span style="font-weight: bolder;">*</span><br><input class="contact-form-email" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="email" size="30" type="text" value="">
            <p></p>
            Mensaje<span style="font-weight: bolder;">*</span><br>
            <textarea class="contact-form-email-message" cols="25" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="email-message" rows="5"></textarea>
            <p></p>
            <input class="contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-submit" type="button" value="Enviar">
            <p></p>
            <div style="text-align: center; max-width: 222px; width: 100%">
               <p class="contact-form-error-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message"></p>
               <p class="contact-form-success-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message"></p>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo especifica para que formulario es ese botón

```
 <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```